# Inno-setup: .iis script failes with "could not call proc" error

Tags: inno-setup

I have an inno setup script that uses a custom dll. Dll is written in FPC (Lazarus) and worked perfectly with my test FPC application (Lazarus too). But when I try to use this dll in my inno script, it failes with "could not call proc" error. 
 My dll function declaration is:

```
procedure GetCRMUserGuid(dbname, host, user, pass:PChar; var res:PChar); stdcall;
```

Declaration of this function in my inno scrips is:

```
procedure GetCRMUserGuid(dbname, host, user, pass:PansiChar; var res:PansiChar); 
 external 'GetCRMUserGuid@files:mslib.dll stdcall delayload setuponly';
```

I try to use it like this:

```
procedure InitializeWizard;
var s:PansiChar;
begin
 GetCRMUserGuid('DBName','127.0.0.1:1433', 'sa', '111', s);
...
end;
```

Can anyone help me and tell, what can cause this problem and how to fix it?
Thanks in advance =)

Comment: The first I can see is a *pointer to anywhere*, the undefined `s` variable... Still, declare you import rather as `GetCRMUserGuid(dbname, host, user, pass: AnsiString; var res: AnsiString)...` and let the Pascal Script engine do the pointer stuff for you. Anyway, I believe that you need to allocate that `s` buffer before passing to the procedure, don't you ?

Comment: @TLama, I tried to add `SetLength(s, 255)` but script failes at this line with the same mistake (could not call proc). May be I should have used something like stralloc, but I don't know any inno analogue for that.

Comment: It's hard to help. It depends on what you're doing inside of your library. For instance [`this should work`](http://pastebin.com/ng2ZUT6n). But note, that it's safer to pass even the buffer length to your library function since it doesn't know this information. If you know the passed buffer length and that won't ever change, then it's fine, but if not, it's better to do it [`this way`](http://pastebin.com/zq6NkJ0T). With the latter way, your library function knows your buffer length limit and knows how much it can copy there. It also returns the copied length which might be useful sometimes.

Comment: @TLama, I tried to edit my script according to your sample, then I tried to use script from your sample only. But it's still "could not call proc"((. The dll containes work with MS SQL Server using sqldb package. Actually, I start to think that problem is in using Lazarus instead of Delphi.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help then. The examples I've posted you I've tested and work for me. I don't know how do you write or read from the parameters in your library, so it's impossible to suggest you a solution.